# Are there formalisms for partial derivatives of scalar functions w.r.t several vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am looking for a correct way to find a derivative of a scalar function over multiple vectors. Let

$$\begin{aligned} f : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n &\to \mathbb{R}, \\ (\vec{x}, \vec{y}) &\mapsto c\end{aligned}$$

Is there any way to formalize partial and exact derivatives on this function or functions of several vectors?

I've searched around, and I'm not even sure if there is a mathematical way to denote functions of this type in a clear, concise way.

Would a general matrix derivative be appropriate here in the event that $m \ne n$?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. dc/dx is a vector with m components. Similarly, dc/dy is a vector with n components. You can also define a vector z as the concatenation of x and y, and see f as a function from R^(n+m) to R, and then take dc/dz, which will be the concatenation of dc/dx and dc/dy. Which option you use depends on what you want to do with those derivatives.

Comment: Why not use $\nabla_x f$ and $\nabla_y f$?